# Azure Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server while connecting sql server using python

Tags: python, sql-server, azure

Hi I'm using sql server V17.3 on Micorsoft Azure platform. I'm trying to upload data from python 3.7 data frame to my table test on sql server. So I wrote following code

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib
dataToUpload=pd.read_csv("intermediate.csv")

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(r'DRIVER=SQLServer};SERVER=nesbaexplsql001.database.windows.net;DATABASE=mydatabase;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;uid=myuid;pwd=my password')
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
engine = create_engine(conn_str)
dataToUpload.to_sql(name='test',con=engine, if_exists='append',index=False)
```

But I'm getting error message

```
DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server. (40607) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server. (40607)') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/dbapi)
```

While executing to_sql. I also tried by putting Trusted_Connection=yes & removing Encryption=True.But I got same error. Can you guide me to resolve this issue?

Comment: have you tried this kind of conn str: (r'Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=ivandb;Uid=your_user_name@your_dbserver;Pwd=your_password;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;') ?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you? If you think it helps you,you could mark it for answer.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to my sample code:

```
import pyodbc
import csv

server = 'tcp:***.database.windows.net'
database = '***'
username = '***'
password = '***'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute("select * from ***")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    print(row[0])
    row = cursor.fetchone()

mycsv = r'D:\insert.csv' # SET YOUR FILEPATH

with open (mycsv, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    columns = next(reader)
    query = 'insert into <TABLE NAME>({0}) values ({1})'
    query = query.format(','.join(columns), ','.join('?' * len(columns)))
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    for data in reader:
        cursor.execute(query, data)
    cursor.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one piece to your connection string:

> Integrated Security = False;

Hope this helps.